# Visual Basic executable running in native mode, but not when starting from debugger

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, native, managed

I have some big problems with my new environment and I think related to managed vs native code.

After my harddrive crashed I installed Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows 8 (which is new to me) and used backups of my Visual Basic .NET code files.

My issue is that the standalone debug executable crashes (with error code 0xc0000409) without me being able to see my source code ('No native symbols in symbol file'). It turns out it is running in native mode (Process: [140] myApp.exe: Native), which I did not think Visual Basic ever did.

When debugging from the GUI I have symbols and, to my surprise, it finds two MyApp.exe in the modules list, one native and one managed.

Some more details, I use ODBC, build for x86, and use .NET 4 client profile. As my project settings are similar or identical with my pre-crash setup I think the configuration problem is in my environment/OS, but I cannot find it after days of searching.

Can I make my standalone executable file execute in managed mode so I can debug it with symbols when it crashes? I have been able to do this for years with my old setup.

Any tips or hints would be very much appreciated.

Comment: VB.Net does not produce "native" applications at all, so you're seeing something that you're either interpreting wrong or that is being reported incorrectly. VB.Net only produces managed executables.

Comment: It is nasty, a stack buffer overflow was detected.  The CLR instantly terminates the app.  It is anti-malware protection mechanism, false warnings are possible but require a seriously corrupted process state or poorly written native code.  Like an ODBC data provider btw.  Starting point is to enable unmanaged debugging so you can get a debugger break when it happens.  Microsoft Symbol server must be enabled, the Call Stack window gives some insight in the cause.

Comment: Well, I do get a chance to debug it, but without source code info the call stack is just clr.dll adress references.

Comment: Are the .pdb files in the same location of the exe?  If it works in debug, you must have the source code.

Comment: Yep, got the pdb in the same place. Something is very fishy; now the same code works without hickup, again. Even 2 days old exe files execute, work and are attachable (and considered managed by vs, lol) which they certainly were not 2 days ago. I think my troubles are not over. ActiveX issues? ODBC, win8 - don't know.